# Popup Window gets stuck behind the main Window - JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, window

So this problem is a bit of a tricky one. This class is for when, in my main program, I can produce a warning window for potentially dangerous actions that the user might do. The nice thing about this window is that if the user clicks OK, then it will return true to my main class. This is done through the following:

```
    private boolean showWarningWindow(String message)
{
    ConfirmationBox warning = new ConfirmationBox(message);
    warning.showAndWait();

    if (warning.isSelected())
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

This method is in my main GUI class. The problem is below, within `ConfirmationBox`. The line `initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);` doesn't work properly. If you accidentally click back to your original GUI window, you're screwed, because now your ConfirmationBox window is trapped under your main window AND because of `Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL`, you won't be able to click anything to get the window back. There isn't a separate application on your taskbar to get the window back in focus and you can't even alt-tab to try and fix it.

Clearly the `Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL` works but somehow it doesn't make the connection that it needs to interrupt the main window.

Try it in your own applications. Add the `showWarningWindow` method to your application and add the ConfirmationWindow class and you will see what I mean. I'm not quite sure how to solve this.

```
package application;

import javafx.beans.property.*;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.*;

public class ConfirmationBox extends Stage
{
    private VBox layout = new VBox();

    private ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper selected = new ReadOnlyBooleanWrapper();

    public boolean isSelected()
    {
        return selected.get();
    }

    public ReadOnlyBooleanProperty selectedProperty()
    {
        return selected.getReadOnlyProperty();
    }

    public ConfirmationBox(String question)
    {
        // Core functionality of the ConfirmationBox.
        setTitle("Warning");
        initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
        initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        setResizable(false);

        layout.setSpacing(10);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        createControls();

        // Add the Label and Buttons to the Confirmation Box.
        layout.getChildren().addAll(new Label(question + "\n\n\n"), createControls());

        java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        setScene(new Scene(layout));
        sizeToScene();  // workaround because utility stages aren't automatically sized correctly to their scene.
    }

    private HBox createControls()
    {
        final Button ok = new Button("OK");
        ok.setOnAction(e -> {
            selected.set(true);
            close();
        });

        final Button cancel = new Button("Cancel");
        cancel.setOnAction(e -> {
            selected.set(false);
            close();
        });

        final HBox controls = new HBox(10, ok, cancel);
        controls.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);

        return controls;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding a call to `initOwner(...)`, passing in a reference to the main window. (Would test but I am away from my computer.)

Comment: I had thought about that too. I'll give it a shot and report back with my findings.

Comment: Wow that did it. You're a god. Thank you!